# Change default columns values multiple libraries

Tags: list, document-library, powershell, managed-metadata, default-value

I have 20 plus libraries that I need to set the default value (to the same value).  The data is from the term store, I also need to do this for a site column.

Is there a tool or script to do this rather than edit each library individually?

Comment: is the column in Managed Metadata column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell scripting for this

Sample code

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb http://siteurl
$spList = $spWeb.GetListFromUrl("/Lists/ListName/AllItems.aspx")
$spField = $spList.Fields["Field Name"]
$spField.DefaultValue = "1;#Term Name" #1 is term ID
$spField.Update()
```